# regular expression lookahead, greedy, whatever

Tags: regex, greedy

I want to get 'abc' and '3.1' out of 'abc3.1'. Here is my regex '(.*)(\d+(.\d+)?)?' and it give me only one group 'abc3.1'. looks like the '?' make the 2nd group non-greedy. Thanks for help.

edit: the string may not be ended with float. And it is utf-8 encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
([a-z]+)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/sD4qH6), see the capture groups in the right pane.

**Explanation**

- `([a-z]+)` captures one or more lower-case letters to Group 1.
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` captures one or more digits, and, optionally, a period, and one or more digits to Group 2.

**What Was the Problem?**

- The greedy `(.*)` is allowed to match all the characters in the string, and does.
- This group `(\d+(.\d+)?)?` is made optional by the `?`, so the dot-star was allowed to keep the entire match without backtracking.

Comment: Saw your update that it doesn't have to be a float. Updated the regex, demo and explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex to get `3.1` and `abc` to get stored inside different groups. A character class is used to capture digits or dots.

```
(.*?)([\d\.]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fG1nS7)

The first `(.*?)` makes the regex non greedy and captures only the text before the Number or a dot. In our case it's the first number.

When the regex engine saw a number or a dot, it starts capturing into another group.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. I need 'abc' as well.

Comment: sorry I updated as well. It may not ended with float.

Comment: It captures numbers also.

Answer (score 1):

In your regex `(.*)(\d+(.\d+)?)?` the last `?` doesn't make the second group non greedy, it makes it optional.

Use this with the dot escaped:

```
(.*)(\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

if the second group is mandatory, or:

```
(\D*)(\d+(\.\d+)?)?
```

if it's optional.

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

For Integer / Double / Float

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/', '', "abc3.1");
```

Output

```
3.1
```

For Alphabets

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', "abc3.1");
```

Output

```
abc
```